# On my system just start Firefox

Tags: release-loki

suddenly, only Firefox starts on my computer, no other program starts; terminal, files, ... none.

I can not leave the system either, the option to shut down the computer does not work, nothing works except firefox. I am using the latest updated version. Both firefox and elementary os.

Regards

Comment: and if you force shutdown and then start again

Answer (score 0):

I have tried again, a new installation, this time install the Sparky distribution with the Pantheon desktop, that is, Elementary .... And it has happened to me exactly the same, Has been to modify a file as root using Pantheon Files like a "New Window as Administrator" option, and The system fails again with the same problems discussed.

It seems clear that the problem comes from the heart of Elementary, the Sparky distribution is Debian + Elementary, and still has the same bug as the original Elementary.

Will I expect a new version of Elementary, does anyone know by when?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

I have reinstalled elementary and the same thing happened to me again, it happens when I open pantheon-files as sudo, I modify some file as sudo and when I leave I encounter the same problem, I can not access any program except those that were open , And when I close them do not reopen, just open firefox.

Abandoning elementary, the system is fine, clean and easy to use, but when something like opening pantheon-files like sudo is a problem ....

Comment: GUI applications should never be run with sudo, Pantheon Files has a "New Window as Administrator" option that runs this properly.

Comment: Thansk Lewis for your help. I have reinstalled elementary again, one more time ... And i have not used sudo. I have used the "New Window as Administrator" option, but the result is the same, my system has become unusable ... I can not normally turn off the computer, I have to force the power off from the power button. Regards